# Mostrar el calendario entero de un año sólo usando while en python

Tags: python, while, calendar

El ejercicio consiste en usar while y no el "calendar" que por suerte trae python.

Se trata de introducir por teclado un año y el día de la semana en el que comenzó el año, por ejemplo: Si el año empezó en lunes, pues se introduce 1, si es como en 2021 que el año empezó en viernes, pues se introduce un 5.
Se debe mostrar por pantalla el calendario con todos los meses de ese año, de Enero a Diciembre.
El código que tengo es el siguiente, pero no sé qué he hecho mal, si le introduzco 2021 me muestra  "Enero - Día 1 viernes"

```
print("Introduce el año que quieres ver")
ano = int(input())

print("Introduce el día de la semana en el que empezó el año (1- Lunes, 2- Martes...): ")
semana = int(input())

mes = 1
dia = 1
finMes = 1

while(mes<=12):
    if(mes == 1):
        print("-------------------------\nEnero\n-------------------------\n")
        break
    if(mes == 2):
        print("-------------------------\nFebrero\n-----------------------\n")
        break
    if(mes == 3):
        print("-------------------------\nMarzo\n-------------------------\n")
        break
    if(mes == 4):
        print("-------------------------\nAbril\n-------------------------\n")
        break
    if(mes == 5):
        print("-------------------------\nMayo\n--------------------------\n")
        break
    if(mes == 6):
        print("-------------------------\nJunio\n-------------------------\n")
        break
    if(mes == 7):
        print("-------------------------\nJulio\n-------------------------\n")
        break
    if(mes == 8):
        print("-------------------------\nAgosto\n------------------------\n")
        break
    if(mes == 9):
        print("-----------------------\nSeptiembre\n----------------------\n")
        break
    if(mes == 10):
        print("------------------------\nOctubre\n------------------------\n")
        break
    if(mes == 11):
        print("------------------------\nNoviembre\n----------------------\n")
        break
    if(mes == 12):
        print("------------------------\nDiciembre\n----------------------\n")
        break
mes = mes+1

while(finMes!=0):
    if(semana == 1):
        print('Día %u Lunes' % dia)  
        break
    if(semana == 2):
        print('Día %u Martes' % dia)  
        break
    if(semana == 3):
        print('Día %u Miércoles' % dia)  
        break
    if(semana == 4):
        print('Día %u Jueves' % dia)  
        break
    if(semana == 5):
        print('Día %u Viernes' % dia)  
        break
    if(semana == 6):
        print('Día %u Sábado' % dia)  
        break
    if(semana == 7):
        print('Día %u Domingo' % dia)  
        break


    if(semana == 7): 
        semana = semana = 1
    else:
        semana = semana+1

    if(mes==1 or mes==3 or mes==5 or mes==7 or mes==8 or mes==10 or mes==12): #meses que tienen 31 días
        if(dia==31):
            finMes = 0
    elif(mes==4 or mes==6 or mes==9 or mes==11): #meses que tienen 30
        if(dia==30):
            finMes = 0
    else:
        if(ano%4==0 and ano%100!=0 or ano%400==0): 
            if(dia==29):
                finMes = 0
            else:
                if(dia == 28):
                    finMes=0
    
    dia = dia+1
    dia=1
    finMes=1
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

La instrucción `break` en Python hace que termine el `while` en la primera iteración. Eso explica porque sólo imprime Enero.

La solución inmediata es eliminar los `break` (o reemplazarlos por `continue`) e indentar el incremento de la variable de control, quedando así:

```
while(mes<=12):
    if(mes == 1):
        print("-------------------------\nEnero\n-------------------------\n")
    if(mes == 2):
        print("-------------------------\nFebrero\n-----------------------\n")
    if(mes == 3):
        print("-------------------------\nMarzo\n-------------------------\n")
    if(mes == 4):
        print("-------------------------\nAbril\n-------------------------\n")
    if(mes == 5):
        print("-------------------------\nMayo\n--------------------------\n")
    if(mes == 6):
        print("-------------------------\nJunio\n-------------------------\n")
    if(mes == 7):
        print("-------------------------\nJulio\n-------------------------\n")
    if(mes == 8):
        print("-------------------------\nAgosto\n------------------------\n")
    if(mes == 9):
        print("-----------------------\nSeptiembre\n----------------------\n")
    if(mes == 10):
        print("------------------------\nOctubre\n------------------------\n")
    if(mes == 11):
        print("------------------------\nNoviembre\n----------------------\n")
    if(mes == 12):
        print("------------------------\nDiciembre\n----------------------\n")
    mes = mes+1
```

Pero hay una solución mejor, que es reemplazar todos esos `ifs` con una lista de meses, así:

```
meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"]
for mes in range(12):
    print(f"-------------------------\n{meses[mes]}\n-------------------------\n")
```

Hace lo mismo que la anterior, pero es más compacta. El `for` se encarga de llevar la variable de control `mes`.

Para formar el título usamos los *f-string*, que es una cadena normal donde tienes escritas **expresiones Python** encerradas entre `{}`. Si a ese string normal le pones una `f` por delante, Python evalua la expresión y la reemplaza dentro del string antes de pasarla al `print`.

En este caso, la expresión es

```
meses[mes]
```

con lo que recuperamos el nombre del mes desde la lista.

Fijate que `mes` varia entre 0 y 11, lo que es más conveniente internamente. La diferencia sólo se nota si imprimes el mes como número, en cuyo caso tienes que sumarle 1.

Sólo te queda agregar la impresión de los días.

**Edición: versión `while`**

La versión con `while` es más larga:

```
meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"]
mes = 0
while mes < len(meses):
    print(f"-------------------------\n{meses[mes]}\n-------------------------\n")
    mes += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que tenemos un año y mes que has entrado:

```
y = 2021
m = 11
```

Se calcula si el año es bisiesto:

```
es_bisiesto = y % 4 == 0 and y % 100 != 0 or y % 400 == 0 # True o False
```

El siguiente pedazo de código es "opcional" ya que estás entrando por teclado qué día cae el primero. Sin embargo, hay una fórmula que puede [calcular qué número de día es cualquier día del año](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algoritmia/Algoritmo_para_calcular_el_d%C3%ADa_de_la_semana). No voy a explicar cómo se calcula esto, lo puedes leer en internet en alguna documentación. Solo usaré los cálculos.

```
mod_days = [[0,3,3,6,1,4,6,2,5,0,3,5], [0,3,4,0,2,5,0,3,6,1,4,6]]
M = mod_days[int(es_bisiesto)][m-1] # Modulo de la cantidad de dias transcurridos
first_day = ((y-1)%7 + ((y-1)//4 - (3*((y-1)//100 + 1)//4))%7 + M + 1%7) % 7
```

Las líneas del párrafo anterior las puedes omitir si entras por teclado qué día es el 1ro.

Ahora se puede declarar una lista con los días que tiene cada mes del año:

```
dias_feb = 29 if es_bisiesto else 28 # 28 o 29
dxmes = [31, dias_feb, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

Finalmente se imprime el calendario de ese mes:

```
meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", 
"Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"]

print(f'{meses[m-1]} de {y}')
weekday = 0 # 0-Do, 1-lu,...
cur_day = 1
print(f'Do Lu Ma Mi Ju Vi Sa')
while cur_day <= dxmes[m-1]:
    if weekday < first_day: # Dias que van en blanco
        print('   ', end='')
    else:
        print(f'{cur_day:<2} ', end='')
        cur_day += 1
    weekday += 1
    if not weekday%7: # Si llegó al fin de la semana, saltar una linea
        print()
```

Produce la siguiente salida:

```
Noviembre de 2021
Do Lu Ma Mi Ju Vi Sa
   1  2  3  4  5  6
7  8  9  10 11 12 13
14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30
```

Con eso ya puedes imprimir el mes que quieras. Incluso puedes imprimir el calendario completo de un año usando un `for m in range(1, 13)` o si es obligatorio, un `while m <= 12`. También puedes meter lo anterior en una o varias funciones y le vas pasando de uno en uno el mes desde enero (1) hasta diciembre (12).

Comment: Gracias a tu calculo, me di cuenta de un error de calculo en mis funciones! Determinaba mal el año bisiesto (para mi era bisiesto si era multiplo de 4) Gracias!!!